# Lightning Design System - Custom Icon Styling Not Working On My iOS app

Tags: ios, lightning-design-system

As per the LDS guidelines, I did the following

```
pod install
```

and then added the following to my ViewController

```
#import <DesignSystem/DesignSystem.h>

UIImage* customIcon = [UIImage sldsIconCustom:SLDSIconCustom1 withSize:SLDSSquareIconSmall];
```

but I keep getting compilation errors for DesignSystem files not being found. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting an error about these files not being found, then it means either your pod isn't installed or the pod configuration file is not correct. The sequence of steps to be followed here is

1) Edit your podfile and add this line

```
pod 'DesignSystem'
```

2) Run

```
pod install
```

3) Then import the file

```
#import <DesignSystem/DesignSystem.h>
```

4) Try opening the above `.h` file in XCode. If the pod installed correctly, you should be able to navigate to this file by clicking on it

5) Then, add your custom styling in the ViewController. It should work fine

```
UIImage* customIcon = [UIImage sldsIconCustom:SLDSIconCustom1 withSize:SLDSSquareIconSmall];
```

Comment: So apparently my pod file was screwed up. I fixed it and followed the above steps, works now!